# Where is the best place to put the export/upload function for a data table function?

Tags: buttons, tables, data-tables

There's two Scenarios:

**V1** Export appears above the top right but only shows to a specific tab, it is hidden if it is not available in other tabs.

**V2** Export appears under the tab where it is only available to.

here's the screenshot:
[image]

Which one do you guys think is more appropriate and why?

Answer (score 1):

[Gestalt laws of proximity](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/laws-of-proximity-uniform-connectedness-and-continuation-gestalt-principles-2#:%7E:text=The%20law%20of%20proximity%20describes,are%20separate%20from%20each%20other.&text=In%20written%20material%2C%20the%20law,of%20text%20as%20a%20whole.) would suggest you go with version 2.

Since in your design, tabs delineate different data groupings (each with their own conditions for export), the closer the action is the object (the data set under the tab), the more related they appear.

From the Nielsen Norman Group: [Closeness of Actions and Objects in GUI Design](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/closeness-of-actions-and-objects-gui/)

> One of the oldest principles of human-computer interaction is that things that are close together on the screen are seen as related.